# Equivalence of an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am given this expression:

$$\frac{f^2}{g} + f$$

And then I am asked if it is equivalent to:

a) $$\frac{f}{g}(f+g)$$
b) $$f(\frac{f}{g}+f)$$
c) $$f^2(\frac{a}{g}-\frac{1}{f})$$

Once I distribute a) I see how it is the answer. However, I don't know how to get there if I wasn't given answer choices. If I wasn't given answer choices I would have done this:

$$\frac{f^2}{g} + f$$
$$f(\frac{f}{g} + 1)$$

**How do I get to answer a)?**

*Answer a) is:
$$\frac{f}{g}(f+g)$$

Comment: If all those expressions are correct, none of them are the right answer. Is it $\frac{f}{g}(f+g)$ in a)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiplying out we have $$f\left(\frac{f}{g}+1\right)=\frac{f^2}{g}+f$$ since $f\cdot f=f^2$ after the correction
 we have $$\frac{f^2}{g}+f=f\left(\frac{f}{g}+1\right)=\frac{f}{g}(f+g)$$

Comment: You did not read my question, I meant how to get to answer a). Edited question for clarity.

Comment: but the answer a) is not true

Comment: it is not the same like the given expression

Comment: My apologies, I have fixed answer a)

Comment: I get it, it just seemed a bit odd at first because when I factor stuff out, I never considered factoring out $$1/g$$

Comment: this is nice that you got it

Answer (score 3):

Well after you get $$f(\frac fg+1)$$
One could try to make it even simpler by simplifying $$\frac{f}{g}+1=\frac{f+g}g$$
Which gives the desired result
$$\frac{f}{g}(f+g)$$
Anyway such things aren't intuitive as the meaning of simplified isn't precise so one could argue that first expression is as good as is the last. I don't think anyone would say your answer is wrong if there weren't given options.

Comment: Thank you for the answer tiny rick!